# Bill of materials database recursive

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new in the sqlite world and I'm writing an app for create recipies of ingredient and I need to create the label of ingredient for the recipies.

I have this table tb_composizioni

```
id      id_ricetta  id_ingrediente  id_ricetta_livello  qty
"1"     "1"         "51"            "0"                 "1000.0"
"2"     "1"         "3"             "0"                 "400.0"
"3"     "2"         "186"           "0"                 "640.0"
"4"     "2"         "94"            "0"                 "30.0"
"5"     "2"         "51"            "0"                 "30.0"
"6"     "3"         "0"             "2"                 "1000.0"
"7"     "3"         "0"             "1"                 "100.0"
```

and I would like to create a "bill of material"
the recipie 3 are compose by 1000gr of recipie 2 and 100gr of recipie 1

this is my query

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  lista_ingredienti(id_ricetta,id_ingrediente,qty,level) AS (
    VALUES('3',0,0,0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tb_composizioni.id_ricetta_livello, tb_composizioni.id_ingrediente, tb_composizioni.qty, lista_ingredienti.level+1
      FROM tb_composizioni JOIN lista_ingredienti ON tb_composizioni.id_ricetta=lista_ingredienti.id_ricetta
     ORDER BY 3 desc 
  )
SELECT  id_ricetta, id_ingrediente , qty FROM lista_ingredienti
```

and the result is:

```
id_ricetta  id_ingrediente  qty
"3"         "0"             "0"
"2"         "0"             "1000.0"
"0"         "186"           "640.0"
"1"         "0"             "100.0"
"0"         "51"            "71.42"
"0"         "3"             "28.57"
"0"         "51"            "30.0"
"0"         "94"            "30.0"
```

I would like to obtain the label of ingredients, so I have to rescale by the total of recipie.
the total of recipie 1 is 1400gr and the total of the recipie 2 is 700gr.
If I rescale the recipie 1 for the qty in the recipie 3 so the factor is 100/1400 = 0.0714, the second rescale is
the recipie 2, so the factor is 1000/700 = 1.4285
Is possible to obtain the table rescaled like this:

```
id_ricetta  id_ingrediente  qty
"3"         "0"             "0"
"2"         "0"             "1000.0"
"0"         "186"           "914.2"
"1"         "0"             "100.0"
"0"         "51"            "71.4"
"0"         "3"             "28.5"
"0"         "51"            "42.8"
"0"         "94"            "42.8"
```

and for the final label of ingredient like this:

```
id_ricetta  id_ingrediente  qty
"3"         "0"             "0"
"0"         "186"           "914.2"
"0"         "51"            "114.2"
"0"         "94"            "42.8"
"0"         "3"             "28.5"
```

this is the .dump file sql:

```
CREATE TABLE "tb_composizioni" (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `id_ricetta`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `id_ingrediente`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `id_ricetta_livello`    INTEGER,
    `qty`   REAL DEFAULT 0,
);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (1,1,51,0,1000.0);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (2,1,3,0,400.0);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (5,2,186,0,640.0);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (9,2,94,0,30.0);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (15,3,0,2,1000.0);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (16,3,0,1,100.0);
INSERT INTO `tb_composizioni` VALUES (17,2,51,0,30.0);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query I.e. please provide a `.dump` via SQLite command line tool of a suitably tailored toy database.

Comment: Is it possible for the same recipe ID to have actual ingredients and sub-recipes in the database?

Comment: I have add .dump file